# Why does unreal engine use c# to provide some functionality and features (like automation tools)

Tags: c#, c++11, unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine is mainly written in c++. But there are some things that are written in c#.

1> So what functionalities are written in c#?

2> And also are there any benefits of using c# instead of c++ in those cases?

And since unreal engine developers often have panel discussions and forums or documentations detailing their decisions. It would be great if someone can provide a link to them discussing or detailing why they used c# over c++ for implementing those features.

[unrealEngine screenshot with .cs search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOUl9.png)

https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine

Comment: why do you think that UE uses C#?

Comment: @IłyaBursov if i remember right you do have the option to use c# in UE in some cases. However the support is limited and you can't directly access the game object.

Comment: What what they are each good for? c++ : maximum performance, c#: if you dont want memory leak and ugly syntax of c++

Comment: Because I use unreal engine, and it has cs code.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M can you point to the c# code in UE engine itself?

Comment: @Steve No I am not talking about me using cs code with UE. But UE itself using cs code to perform some functionality. My initial guess is that it does to perform some windows tasks or Visual Studio related setup or graphic (or UI) related stuff. But I am not sure.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M cs is just a language it has nothing to do with OS or what so ever. Think of it as an embedded language. As of why? idk. Maybe cuz of the feature i mentioned before, letting ppl who hates c++ write some c# code

Comment: UE is written in C++, there is no C# in engine, there could be some additional utilities or VS plugins written in C#, but not in engine per se, this could be done because these parts do not require optimal performance or just easier to code

Comment: @IłyaBursov I have added a link to unreal engine github and also an image with .cs search on the Engine, to the original post.

Comment: @Steve lol maybe. But I think there has to be more reason for it.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M so? all files are not in engine, but some build or automation tools, non of them are used by engine itself

Comment: @IłyaBursov You do know 'Unreal Engine' is the complete name of the complete application (and not just the engine in the application, although the engine IS the main feature). So when I said 'Unreal Engine' I was talking about all of it and not just the "engine" module. Maybe read the question before you get so defensive about arbitrary issues. I am also a c++ coder.  So its good to know the "engine" is written completely in c++. But I wanted to know why they used c# in the "application". That's all.

Comment: It's frequently more efficient to build things like utilities and UI in a higher-level language. Just look at Visual Studio: the UI is written in C# (WPF), but the compiler, etc. are certainly not. Another benefit is that it's a lot easier to find reasonably-priced C# developers than it is for C++.

Comment: @3Dave Thanks for the reply. I was thinking the same thing, but wasn't sure if those things were done to improve performance or improve efficiency of building the project. Because (as you pointed out) for some functionalities like UI, it is more efficient to do it in higher-level languages because there are already a lot of libraries and support for that stuff. And its not smart to re invent the wheel for little benefit. I suspect Unreal has used c# for things that happen just once, like building the project and stuff. And c++ of the heavy stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Unreal Engine uses .NET utilities for various functionality that supports the main engine but is not used at runtime, and is therefore less performance critical, such as: [Unreal Build Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/BuildTools), [Swarm Agent and Swarm Coordinator](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/LightingAndShadows/Lightmass/UnrealSwarmOverview), [Automation Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Automation) and [Network Profiler](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/Tools/NetworkProfiler).

The reason to use c# and .NET over c++ for such utilities is most likely faster speed of development.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking (I commented it to @3Dave like 5mins before your reply, but I wasn't sure). Also didn't know about Swarm Agent and Swarm Coordinator. Thanks for answering so clearly and also providing helpful links. I don't know why people are getting so defensive and also down voting the question. Its not like I asked something like, which is better C# or C++. Every language has its advantage and I just wanted to know what the advantage was in this case.

Comment: The question was voted as primarily opinion-based because we can't know for sure what the reasoning was for decisions made by Epic Games. My answer provides a reasonable explanation, though not an authoritative one. As for the downvotes, I can't say for sure. Perhaps they only read the title and said to themselves "LIES! UE is written in c++!".

Comment: @Rotem I work with (not for) Epic. Your explanation is pretty much what I heard when someone else in the room asked the C# question.

Comment: @Rotem Actually Epic Games has many forums and panel discussions where they do discuss these type of things and explain why they made certain decisions. Like when they changed to iwyu from version ~4.15, they did provide a detailed explaination. Before asking my question here, I tried to search those things but didn't find it. The only reason I asked it (as a sidenote in the last line of my question) is because maybe someone read about it or saw a video and can provide a link.

Comment: @Rotem Even c++ developers and designers provide reasoning for their decisions. Like why there is no size() function for std::forward_list.
Also 2 out of the 5 who voted, I don't think know much about C++ or C# (they are mostly php and java coders), and most likely, none of them know about unreal engine or unity or game development in general.

Comment: @Rotem I think the system is flawed in this way, by alowing people who don't know about a topic can flag questions just based
on the "points" they earned answering questions about completely different things. Sorry for ranting to YOU (the person who helped me). But I guess there is no one else except you and 3Dave here to get my point. BTW Thanks for the reply, I guess I'll have to change the question.

Comment: Personally I don't see that as a flaw. I know nothing about some topics, but I can always spot a terribly written question. Similarly the users who downvoted may have had their reasons. I suggest you don't give it too much weight.

Comment: @Rotem I don't really mind the downvotes. But I do mind someone potentially closing a question because they don't like the wording. (In my case I don't care, cos its not critical). Usually people who don't know about a subject can't word the question properly. But people who do know can easily make out what that person is trying to ask. I myself have answered a lot of questions on tutorial sites and places like youtube, that were asked in broken english. But since I knew about the topic, I could easily figure out what they were asking.

Comment: @Rotem  Imagine if this was a critical issue and people blocked it because they didn't like the wording. The guy wouldn't be able to get an answer till the mods cleared him. Which could be days (or never). I do get your point about asking proper questions. But I don't think my wording was that bad. And u n 3Dave could figure out. All I am saying is that if someone is freezing answers to a question, they should be more responsible. Cos ppl usually come 2 'SO' as a last resort (like me). Sry I knw I am wasting ur time. But I hope u get my point. I'll stop commenting now :D Thanks 4 ur help